# How to get resources from Maven project

Tags: java, maven

Maven is ***very*** difficult. I would like to reference the resources in my code. But I can't.

I have got a project set up in Eclipse. In it I have the following structure

```
src
---main
--------java
------------myclasses
-------resources
------------sometextfiles.txt
```

The relevant part of the pom.xml is as follows:

```
<build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        <plugins>

          <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <filters>
         <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
               </excludes>
            </filter>
         </filters>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>main.java.Console.TBB_SQLBuilder</mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I do Maven build clean install from Eclipse usually the target folder doesn't generate the resources folder. A bug which others have suffered from. I think this can be remedied by just creating the resources folder manually in the target folder but that's not very useful. But even if I do this I don't seem to be able to use the resources:

My code:

```
public class Checkers {
     ArrayList<String> che2=new ArrayList<String>();
     static URL dictionary;
     String n=null;

    public Checkers() {

    }

    public static String FindNReplace(String n) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("FindNReplaceDictionary.txt")),2048);

String [] split=null;
        ArrayList<String> orig= new ArrayList<String>();
        String [] orig_arr=null;
        ArrayList<String> newDoc= new ArrayList<String>();
        String [] newDoc_arr=null;      

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                split=line.split(":");
                System.out.println("SPLIT"+split);

                                 }

               }
```

}

I've also tried FindNReplaceDictionary.txt with a leading "/" but no joy.

So to deal with my confusion here are my questions
1. How do I reference the resource in Eclipse so that I can run it as a java project at least
2. How do I reference the resource once the Maven project has undergone build clean install
3. Do I need to change anything between running it as a java project and doing a Maven build

Yes I am confused about the whole thing.

Comment: No resources folder should be created, whatever is in the resources folder is copied to the location which will be the root of the classpath. The root of a jar in a local client application, WEB-INF/classes in a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts in "resources" folder are copied to your final packaged/compiled classpath. In case of web application it will be 'WEB-INF/classes' other instances it will go to 'classes' folder.

if you want another resource folder you can specify that in build

```
<build>     
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/anotherresourcesfolder</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

You will not be able to change a maven project to eclipse project easily, because maven has standard opinionated folder structure